# How to access ActiveRecord model using Rail's ActionCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

```
class NoteChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def save_note(data)
    note = current_user.notes.find(data[:id])
    note.content = data[:content]
    note.save!
  end

end
```

The message is received and the data parameters are populated correctly. However, changes to `note` are not persisted in the db. Am I misunderstanding ActionCable?

Am I not able to access ActiveRecord models stored in the MySQL database through ActionCable?

Answer (score 0):

Ok turned out the code was generally fine. I'm using Puma as the web server locally, and that doesn't display error messages in the console like `rails s` would.

Instead I had to tail the development log to see the errors:
`tail -f log/development.log`

It turns out that the error in this case was a 404. I should have been accessing the hash key as a string and not a symbol:

```
note = current_user.notes.find(data["id"])
```